# Filter out results and answers that involve jQuery

Tags: discussion, javascript, jquery

Is there any easy way in Stack Overflow to filter out all solutions that involve jQuery. Due to licensing restrictions I only want to view solutions that use pure JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, you can search by tags. And try to find the answer you need. I fyou don't find the answer post a new quation and specify you want Vanilla JS

Comment: I suspect you're mistaken about licensing restrictions.  The MIT license is *extremely* liberal.

Comment: Search for `[javascript] -jquery is:q`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can search text and filter by tags and try to find the answer you need.

1. To look for a tag use: `[tagName]`
2. Too exclude a tag use the minus before it: `-[tagName]`

If you don't find the answer you are looking for, post a new question and specify you want Vanilla JS  in the solution.

In the right upper corner you can find a search field, if you use `[javascript]` you will get postes tagged javascript. You can also combine like `[javascript] for loop`.

Another way is to click the tags on the right column of Stackoverflow.

- About the MIT license you can read more [**here**](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
- You can find more info about Advanced Search [**here**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? don't agree with my answer?

Comment: -1 not enough jquery

Comment: I didn't down vote, but without explaining `-[jquery]`, this answer is near useless. jQuery questions are also tagged as JavaScript. Searching for `[javascript]` will give as many jQuery answers as non-jQuery.

Comment: @Matt, good point. Added that info, beside the link to the whole adv srch page.